# Callback function correct?

Tags: javascript

I am coding a game. I need to call `loadGameDiv` after `game.start()` is fully executed because of the AJAX calls that `game.start()` is doing. I am trying to use a callback function but the game object that is passed to `loadGameDiv` is still missing some parameters.

```
var game = {
    stage: [],
    start: function(callback){
            this.stage = Stage.makeStage();
            callback(game);
    },

var gameStart= function(){
  game.start(callback);

  function callback(game) {
    loadGameDiv(game);
  }
}

var loadGameDiv = function(gameObject) {
  console.log(gameObject.stage[0]);
}
```

Comment: Is `Stage.makeStage()` doing the Ajax requests?  If so, you're calling that and then immediately calling the callback without waiting for the Ajax requests to finish.  `makeStage()` needs to take care of the callback.

Comment: passing back game seems strange...

Answer (score 0):

I see no ajax calls. If `Stage.makeStage()` does an ajax call, simply putting a callback after it will not ensure post-response execution. You will need to pass a callback to the ajax call.

Also, `callback(game);` is probably not doing what you want. I'm guessing you want to pass `this` to `loadGameDiv()`?